# Linq Get Latest record for a set of Values by its latest date entered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having issue figuring out how to filter a set of values from my Database table by the latest date entered

so far I have the following linq statement

```
List<int> vals = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Context.Table.Where(x => x.Col1 == col1 && vals.Contains(x.Col2)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateEntered).Distinct().ToList();
```

It just seems to returning all rows? So basically for each `vals` items e.g. 1,2,3,4 it should return one row.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: there may be multiple rows in your DB containing  vals for Col2. Run a plain SQL query to confirm

Comment: Could you share your table rows? Or what is the result of equal sql query?

Comment: what is  `col1` equal to?

Comment: I don't think `Distinct` is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Col1 is a `Foreign Key` and is same for each record(s). Col2 contains multiple rows for each `vals` as @Peru mentioned.

Comment: Group by should solve if that is what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the latest for each record, you can use a `GroupBy` with a `Select`:

```
Context.Table
    .Where(x => x.Col1 == col1 && vals.Contains(x.Col2))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Col2)
    // order by descending on the group
    // and then take the first
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateEntered).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: that works however the query seems very slow? Also is it safer to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()` incase there are no records for one of the `vals`?

Comment: @Kevin Not really, the Where filters all irrelevant records. Yeah, the query generated by Entity Framework might not be the best for this

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is group by the `Col2` in vals so you can select the latest of each group. Using LINQ Lambda syntax:

```
List<int> vals = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var ans = Context.Table.Where(x => x.Col1 == Col1 && vals.Contains(x.Col2))
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Col2)
                       .Select(xg => xg.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateEntered).First())
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks however the `Linq` is somewhat slow in fetching data.

Comment: I think you would need to analyze the generated SQL to see why.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkIn = iclock_transaction
               .Where(x => x.punch_state == "0" )
               // .AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(x=>new { x.emp_code,x.punch_time.Date })
               // order by descending on the group
               // and then take the first
               .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x.punch_time).First())
               .ToList();

//********* Perfectly work with check out   ********
var checkOut = iclock_transaction
               .Where(x => x.punch_state == "1")
               // .AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(x => x.emp_code)
               // order by descending on the group
               // and then take the first
               .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.punch_time).First())
               .ToList();

iclock_transaction = checkIn.Concat(checkOut).ToList();
```

Comment: This is going to do a client side grouping - i.e.useless in production environment where the amount of data is large.